# Batch program to check if process exist

Tags: file, batch-file

I need to get the processes from a control file but it wont work. Please help! Thanks.

```
For /f %%a in (processesList.ctrl) do (

For /f %%x in ('tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %%a"' DO IF %%x == %%a goto FOUND

echo Not running 

:FOUND
Echo running

)

Pause
```

Comment: Don't put labels inside of loops. It breaks absolutely everything.

Answer (score 0):

use `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the start of your script , A for loop is executed as a single instruction , all values will be initialized before execution and to override that we need to enable delayed expansion.